# Parts of Speech classification problem - Neural Network not learning

Tags: java, neural-network, backpropagation

I am writing a NN to classify Polish parts of speech. When I launch the neural network I noticed that the weights get constantly increased and hidden the error (cost) get's to maximum instead of being minimized.

Here is my Network Class:

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.lang.Math;
    import java.util.Random;
    import java.text.DecimalFormat;

    public class NeuralNetwork {

        // constructor generates random weights and trains the neural network
        public NeuralNetwork() {
            randomise();
            System.out.println("The network has been initialized with random weights.");
            train();
            System.out.println("Weights have been adjusted and the network is trained.\nProceeding to classification.");
        }

        // format of decimal values to be printed out onto the console
        private DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");

        // boolean value - if true print system logs
        private boolean printLogs = false;

        // maximal accepted length of a word = 30 letters
        private double[] input = new double[32 * 32 + 20];

        // there are 10 parts of speech in the polish language
        private double[] output = new double[10];

        // abstract decision to have 20 nodes in the hidden layer -> (30 + 10) / 2
        private double[] hiddenLayer = new double[20];

        // 20 nodes in hidden layer x 30 input nodes -> each input times it's wieght is an input for each hidden layer node
        private double[][] weightsForInput = new double [20][32 * 32 + 20];

        // 10 output nodes x 20 hidden layer nodes -> each hidden layer node times it's wieght is an input for each output node
        private double[][] weightsForHiddenLayer = new double[10][20];

        // learning rate
        private double learningRate = 0.1;

    public void generateInputFromWord(String word, int placeInSentence, int sentenceLength) {
        boolean first;
        for (int c = 0; c < word.length(); c++) {
            first = true;
            for (int x = 0; x < 32; x++) {
                if (first && x == convertCharToInt(word.charAt(c)) - 1) {
                    input[32 * c + x] =  1.;
                    first = false;
                }
            }
        }
        input[32 * 32 + (int) Math.round(20. * (double) placeInSentence / sentenceLength) - 1] = 1.;
    }

        // creates output where each node = sigmoid(sum(hiddenLayerNode * wieght))
        private void generateOutput() {
            for(int i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
                double sum = 0;
                for(int j = 0; j < hiddenLayer.length; j++) {
                    sum += hiddenLayer[j] * weightsForHiddenLayer[i][j];
                }
                output[i] = sigmoid(sum);
            }
        }

        // creates hidden layer where each node = sigmoid(sum(inputNode * weight))
        private void generateHiddenLayer() {
            for(int i = 0; i < hiddenLayer.length; i++) {
                double sum = 0;
                for(int j = 0; j < input.length; j++) {
                    sum += input[j] * weightsForInput[i][j];
                }
                hiddenLayer[i] = sigmoid(sum);
            }
        }

        // returns an integer from 1 to 32 for each letter of the polish alphabet
        private int convertCharToInt(char c){
            switch(c){
                case 'a': return 1;
                case '\u0105': return 2;
                case 'b': return 3;
                case 'c': return 4;
                case '\u0107': return 5;
                case 'd': return 6;
                case 'e': return 7;
                case '\u0119': return 8;
                case 'f': return 9;
                case 'g': return 10;
                case 'h': return 11;
                case 'i': return 12;
                case 'j': return 13;
                case 'k': return 14;
                case 'l': return 15;
                case '\u0142': return 16;
                case 'm': return 17;
                case 'n': return 18;
                case '\u0144': return 19;
                case 'o': return 20;
                case '\u00F3': return 21;
                case 'p': return 22;
                case 'r': return 23;
                case 's': return 24;
                case '\u015B': return 25;
                case 't': return 26;
                case 'u': return 27;
                case 'w': return 28;
                case 'y': return 29;
                case 'z': return 30;
                case '\u017A': return 31;
                case '\u017C': return 32;
                default: return 0;
            }
        }

        // populate wieghts and the bias with random values
        private void randomise() {
            Random random = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < weightsForInput.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < weightsForInput[0].length; j++) {
                    weightsForInput[i][j] = random.nextDouble();
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < weightsForHiddenLayer.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < weightsForHiddenLayer[0].length; j++) {
                    weightsForHiddenLayer[i][j] = random.nextDouble();
                }
            }
        }

        // sigmoid function 1 / (1 + e ^ (- x)) returns num in range (0, 1)
        private double sigmoid(double input) {
            return 1 / (1 + Math.pow(Math.E, - input));
        }

        // converts PoS String into size[10] array of classification output
        private double[] generateExpectedOutput(String input) {
            double[] result = new double[10];

            switch(input) {
                case "RZECZOWNIK":
                    result[0] = 1;
                    break;
                case "PRZYMIOTNIK":
                    result[1] = 1;
                    break;
                case "LICZEBNIK":
                    result[2] = 1;
                    break;
                case "ZAIMEK":
                    result[3] = 1;
                    break;
                case "CZASOWNIK":
                    result[4] = 1;
                    break;
                case "PRZYSLOWEK":
                    result[5] = 1;
                    break;
                case "PRZYIMEK":
                    result[6] = 1;
                    break;
                case "SPOJNIK":
                    result[7] = 1;
                    break;
                case "WYKRZYKNIK":
                    result[8] = 1;
                    break;
                case "PARTYKULA":
                    result[9] = 1;
                    break;
            }

            return result;
        }

        // convert output array into one of 10 possible parts of speech
        private POS getPOSFromOutput() {
            int node = 0;
            double max = 0;
            POS result = POS.RZECZOWNIK;
            for(int i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
                if(output[i] > max) {
                    max = output[i];
                    node = i;
                }
            }
            switch(node) {
                case 0:
                    result = POS.RZECZOWNIK;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    result = POS.PRZYMIOTNIK;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    result = POS.LICZEBNIK;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    result = POS.ZAIMEK;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    result = POS.CZASOWNIK;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    result = POS.PRZYSLOWEK;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    result = POS.PRZYIMEK;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    result = POS.SPOJNIK;
                    break;
                case 8:
                    result = POS.WYKRZYKNIK;
                    break;
                case 9:
                    result = POS.PARTYKULA;
                    break;  
            }

            return result;
        }

        // prints a 1D array onto the console
        private void printOneDArray(double[] array, String arrayName) {
            System.out.println(arrayName + ":");
            for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                System.out.print(df.format(array[i]) + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }

        // prints a 2D array onto the console
        private void printTwoDArray(double[][] array, String arrayName) {
            System.out.println(arrayName + ":");
            for(int x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
                for(int y = 0; y < array[x].length; y++) {
                    System.out.print(df.format(array[x][y]) + " ");
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }

        // calculates average error where each output node error = (output - expectedOutput)^2
        private double calculateError(double[] expectedOutput) {
            double error = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
                // calculate sum of quadratic difference
                error += Math.pow(expectedOutput[i] - output[i], 2);
            }
            // average the sum
            return error / expectedOutput.length;
        }

        // calculates new weights for the hidden layer based on current weights and calculated error for a specific training element
        private double[][] calculateNewWeightsForHiddenLayer(double[] expectedOutput) {
            double[][] newWeights = new double[weightsForHiddenLayer.length][weightsForHiddenLayer[0].length];
            for(int i = 0; i < expectedOutput.length; i++) {
                for(int x = 0; x < weightsForHiddenLayer.length; x++) {
                    for(int y =0; y < weightsForHiddenLayer[x].length; y++) {
                        // derivate (weight * hiddenLayer) in respect to weight * derivative (sigmoid(x)) in respect to x * derivative (output - expectedOutput)^2 in respect to output
                        newWeights[x][y] += weightsForHiddenLayer[x][y] - learningRate *
                                            hiddenLayer[y] *
                                            (sigmoid(weightsForHiddenLayer[x][y] * hiddenLayer[y]) * (1 - sigmoid(weightsForHiddenLayer[x][y] * hiddenLayer[y]))) *
                                            2 * (expectedOutput[i] - output[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
            newWeights = calculateAverageArray(newWeights, expectedOutput.length);
            return newWeights;
        }

        // calculates new weights for the input layer based on current weights and calculated error for a specific training element
        private double[][] calculateNewWeightsForInput(double[] expectedOutput) {
            double[][] newWeights = new double[weightsForInput.length][weightsForInput[0].length];
            for(int i = 0; i < expectedOutput.length; i++) {
                for(int x = 0; x < weightsForInput.length; x++) {
                    for(int y = 0; y < weightsForInput[x].length; y++) {
                        // derivative function
                        newWeights[x][y] += weightsForInput[x][y] - learningRate *
                                            input[y] *
                                            (sigmoid(weightsForHiddenLayer[i][x] * hiddenLayer[x]) * (1 - sigmoid(weightsForHiddenLayer[i][x] * hiddenLayer[x]))) *
                                            weightsForHiddenLayer[i][x] *
                                            (sigmoid(weightsForInput[x][y] * input[y]) * (1 - sigmoid(weightsForInput[x][y] * input[y]))) *
                                            2 * (expectedOutput[i] - output[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
            newWeights = calculateAverageArray(newWeights, expectedOutput.length);
            return newWeights;
        }

        // adds two arrays of same size together
        private double[][] addArrays(double[][] arrayOne, double arrayTwo[][]) {
            double sumArray[][] = new double[arrayOne.length][arrayOne[0].length];
            for(int x = 0; x < arrayOne.length; x++) {
                for(int y =0; y < arrayOne[x].length; y++) {
                    sumArray[x][y] = arrayOne[x][y] + arrayTwo[x][y];
                }
            }
            return sumArray;
        }

        // calculates the average for a layer by dividing each element by the amount of elements used to create sum
        private double[][] calculateAverageArray(double[][] array, int counter) {
            double[][] averageArray = new double[array.length][array[0].length];
            for(int x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
                for(int y= 0; y < array[x].length; y++) {
                    averageArray[x][y] = array[x][y] / counter;
                }
            }
            return averageArray;
        }

        // trains the neural network based on a training set in the file training_set.txt
        private void train() {
            try {
                // classification error
                double error = 0;
                double errorSum = 0;
                // count which element is being calculated
                int counter = 0;
                int counterSum = 0;
                // train as long as the error is above 10%
                do{
                    if(printLogs) {
                        printTwoDArray(weightsForInput, "Weights for input");
                        printTwoDArray(weightsForHiddenLayer, "Weights for hidden layer");
                    }
                    // input file with text to be classified
                    File file = new File("training_set.txt"); 
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF8"));
                    // input line of text
                    String line = "";
                    // reseting counter and error sum (for average error calculation) for each new passage through the training set
                    counter = 0;
                    errorSum = 0;
                    // array with temporary weightsForInput
                    double[][] tmpInputWeights = new double[20][32 * 32 + 20];
                    // array for temporary weightsForHiddenLayer
                    double[][] tmpHiddenLayerWeights = new double[10][20];
                    // loop to train each element in the training set
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        counter++;
                        // [0] Word [1] place in sentence [2] sentence length [3] PoS
                        String[] data = line.split(",");
                        generateInputFromWord(data[0], Integer.parseInt(data[1]), Integer.parseInt(data[2]));
                        generateHiddenLayer();
                        generateOutput();
                        error = calculateError(generateExpectedOutput(data[3]));
                        errorSum += error;
                        if(printLogs) {
                            System.out.println(counter + " training element: " + data[0] + " " + data[1] + " " + data[2] + " " + data[3]);
                            printOneDArray(input, "Input layer");
                            printOneDArray(hiddenLayer, "Hidden layer");
                            printOneDArray(output, "Output layer");
                            printOneDArray(generateExpectedOutput(data[3]), "Expected output");
                            System.out.println("\n" + "Error: " + error + "\n");
                        }
                        tmpHiddenLayerWeights = addArrays(tmpHiddenLayerWeights, calculateNewWeightsForHiddenLayer(generateExpectedOutput(data[3])));
                        tmpInputWeights = addArrays(tmpInputWeights, calculateNewWeightsForInput(generateExpectedOutput(data[3])));
                        for(int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
                            input[i] = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    counterSum += counter;
                    br.close();
                    // calculate average weights
                    weightsForHiddenLayer = calculateAverageArray(tmpHiddenLayerWeights, counter);
                    weightsForInput = calculateAverageArray(tmpInputWeights, counter);
                    // calculate average error over all the training set
                    errorSum /= counter;
                    if(printLogs) {
                        System.out.println("\n" + "Average error: " + errorSum + "\n");
                    }
                } while(errorSum > 0.1);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error - main: " + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        // classify a word as one of 10 possible parts of speech
        public POS classify(String word, int placeInSentence, int sentenceLength) {
            generateInputFromWord( word, placeInSentence, sentenceLength);
            generateHiddenLayer();
            generateOutput();
            return getPOSFromOutput();
        }

        // get value in output array
        public double[] getOutput() {
            return output;
        }

    }
```

and sample of my training set:

```
wszyscy,1,7,RZECZOWNIK
jesteśmy,2,7,CZASOWNIK
studentami,3,7,RZECZOWNIK
lub,4,7,SPOJNIK
od,5,7,PRZYIMEK
niedawna,6,7,PRZYSLOWEK
absolwentami,7,7,RZECZOWNIK
```

Is the backpropagation algorithm correct?
I calculate the average weights based on the entire training set.
The new weights are calculated here:

```
private double[][] calculateNewWeightsForHiddenLayer(double[] expectedOutput)
private double[][] calculateNewWeightsForInput(double[] expectedOutput)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When designing a neural network, a very important task is to select a set of suitable features, which are easy for a neural network to work with.

By encoding the position of the word in the same values as the characters itself, you are making it impossible for the network to learn anything, because this maps many, potentially unrelated words to the same encoding.

By using a single scalar for a character, you are making it very very hard for the network to distinguish between characters. Instead, using one-hot encoding may perform better, where each character is represented as a vector of mostly zeros, with a one at the index that corresponds to that character.

If you want to work on a character level and include the position of the word, use a different way to encode position, e.g. by encoding it as a set of secondary inputs, which could be a vector of ones and zeros corresponding to the binary representation of the position of the word.

Usually, neural networks working on natural language use so called word embeddings, where each word is mapped to a unique vector representation that is determined by the context that the word occurs in (e.g. word2vec, Glove).

For part of speech tagging, words around the current word are also relevant to classify the tag. A word may have a different tag depending on the words around it, even though the position of the word in the sentence is the same. This is why the common approach for neural network based part of speech tagging involves recurrent neural networks.

Comment: I've changed my word encoding (edited question). The error is still rising.

Comment: You're never resetting your inputs, so after a while, it will just be filled with ones.